# Scala Match Error Case Prevention

Tags: scala, list, recursion, combinations

I have this function that basically combines *Lists* of *Lists*, but you can ignore that, for that is not the issue:

```
def combinationList[T](ls:List[List[List[T]]]) : List[List[List[T]]] = ls match {
 case head :: Nil  => for(x <- head) yield List(x)
 case head :: tail :: Nil =>
  for {
    hl <- head
    tl <- tail
    if tl.forall(te => !hl.contains(te))
  } yield List(hl, tl)
}
```

This works when I have a *List* with two sub-*lists* but it fails to match when I have more than two. I obviously need to use this function recursively to make a more general case, and I've tried to add the following case at the end of the function:

```
case _ => combinationList(combinationList(ls.tail):::List(ls.head))
```

The logic here is that, imagine we have a List with 3 sub lists, like so:

```
List ( List(1), List(2), List(3) )
```

When I first call the fucntion, it will only match in the last case I mentioned, so, I will call the function with the list's tail (List(2), List(3)), and, in that call, it will match for the second case (head::tail::Nil), then, when it returns, it should be a single List and when added to the list's original head (List(1)::List(2+3)) it should match on the second condition. The issue here is that the return is not a single list (List(2+3)) but rather yet another combination of lists (List(2), List(3)) so it will obviously recursive forever. I've tried to modify the case like this:

```
combinationList(List(combinationList(ls.tail)):::List(ls.head))
```

But it gives me an error ("The expression of type List[List[List[Any]]] doesn't conform to type List[List[List[T]]]"

Any ideas? Thanks.

[EDIT:] This function's purpose is to combine lists in such manner:

```
simplified input: List( List(1,2), List(3), List(4))
simplified output: List( List(1,3,4), List(2,3,4))

real input: List(
             List(List(1), List(3), List(4)), 
             List(List(2), List(3), List(4))
            )
real expected output: List(
                       List(List(1), List(2)), 
                       List(List(1), List(3)), 
                       List(List(1), List(4)), 
                       List(List(3), List(2)), 
                       List(List(3), List(4)), 
                       List(List(4), List(2)), 
                       List(List(4), List(3))
                      )
```

With the real input, the function is able to return the expected output, it only fails when another sub list is added, like so:

```
     input: List(
             List(List(1), List(2)), 
             List(List(3), List(4)),
             List(List(5))
            )
```

The expected output here, would be:

```
     expected output: List(
                       List(List(1), List(3), List(5)), 
                       List(List(1), List(4), List(5)), 
                       List(List(2), List(3), List(5)), 
                       List(List(2), List(4), List(5))
                      )
```

So, the order of the combinations don't really matter much, I can head:::tail or tail:::head, it's the same thing.

Comment: You probably should describe in more detail what the function is supposed to do. "Combining List of Lists" could mean `ls.flatten.flatten`. I don't understand what the type with three nested `List`s means, and why you are trying to glue tails to heads in reversed order. I don't see how one can "ignore that", so: what exactly did you try to do?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Sure thing, I edited the post, hope it helps!

Comment: Your code and your examples don't match. Your code takes `List[List[List[_]]]` but all your examples are `List[List[_]]`.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but it doesn't seem to clarify why there are three levels of nesting in `List[List[List[T]]]`. I see only *two* nesting levels in `input` and `output`.

Comment: @jwvh I'll edit again with a real input, I tried to simplify for better understanding, but I think it only made it more confusing ahah

Comment: uhm... no, still not clearer. What are those `n1`, ... `n5` things? And what is the expected output for the `n`s? Could you please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with input, expected output, such that one can copy-paste it into interpreter and get exactly the same error message that you are getting?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I'm sorry once again, this time I edited with all the information. If you copy-paste the input into the function, it should work (for the first case) and fail (for the second one). the *n1* things were objects, but I simplified to just *INT*, it's the same thing. Any more doubts, please ask.

Comment: In the last "expected output" the closing parentheses `)` don't add up.

Comment: @jwvh my bad!, it's done now.

Comment: I still don't see what the significance of triple nesting is. In all your examples, the innermost lists all have length `1`, without exceptions. Why complicate everything by three nesting levels?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I just simplified it for you, the length of real cases is not always one, and it's relevant that it's triple nested. Regardless, If I remove 1 level, I have to remove 1 level from everything, and the problem maintains. You'll have to take my word for it. Just copy the function and the input and try it yourself, leave the details of significancy with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why you want three levels of nesting. However, the following generic method works with all your examples, both with integers and with lists:

```
def combinationList[T](ls: List[List[T]]): List[List[T]] = {
  def recHelper(remainingLs: List[List[T]], blacklist: Set[T]): List[List[T]] = {
    remainingLs match {
      case Nil => List(Nil)
      case h :: t => for { 
        x <- h.filterNot(blacklist.contains)
        xs <- recHelper(t, blacklist + x)
      } yield x :: xs
    }
  }
  recHelper(ls, Set.empty)
}
```

This implementation doesn't filter out any combinations with `! .contains`, instead it maintains a set of blacklisted elements, and doesn't generate the invalid combinations in the first place.

Some examples:

```
def showExample[T](input: List[List[T]]): Unit = {
  println("=" * 60)
  println(input)
  println("-" * 60)
  for (c <- combinationList(input)) {
    println("  " + c)
  }
}
showExample(List(List(1, 2), List(3), List(4)))
showExample(List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4), List(2, 3, 5)))
showExample(List(
  List(List(1), List(3), List(4)), 
  List(List(2), List(3), List(4))
))
showExample(List(
  List(List(1), List(2)), 
  List(List(3), List(4)),
  List(List(5))
))
```

Output:

```
============================================================
List(List(1, 2), List(3), List(4))
------------------------------------------------------------
  List(1, 3, 4)
  List(2, 3, 4)
============================================================
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4), List(2, 3, 5))
------------------------------------------------------------
  List(1, 2, 3)
  List(1, 2, 5)
  List(1, 3, 2)
  List(1, 3, 5)
  List(1, 4, 2)
  List(1, 4, 3)
  List(1, 4, 5)
  List(2, 3, 5)
  List(2, 4, 3)
  List(2, 4, 5)
  List(3, 2, 5)
  List(3, 4, 2)
  List(3, 4, 5)
============================================================
List(List(List(1), List(3), List(4)), List(List(2), List(3), List(4)))
------------------------------------------------------------
  List(List(1), List(2))
  List(List(1), List(3))
  List(List(1), List(4))
  List(List(3), List(2))
  List(List(3), List(4))
  List(List(4), List(2))
  List(List(4), List(3))
============================================================
List(List(List(1), List(2)), List(List(3), List(4)), List(List(5)))
------------------------------------------------------------
  List(List(1), List(3), List(5))
  List(List(1), List(4), List(5))
  List(List(2), List(3), List(5))
  List(List(2), List(4), List(5))
```

Some hints:

- The more generic versions of the code are often easier to write, because if there are more constraints, there are fewer possibilities to do something wrong. In this case, the triple nesting seems unnecessary.
- The base case is the empty list, not the list with one element
- The recursion must work with lists of arbitrary length, but `x :: y :: Nil` matches only lists of length two.